# Extrair dados de um arquivo json usando o SimpleJson?

Tags: c#, json

Arquivo json que estou usando.

```
{ 
"url" : "https://scontent-gru2-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-     15/s320x320/e15/12523558_1184627644899567_723648549_n.jpg", 
"low_resolution" : "https://scontent-gru2-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfp1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/1168874_1275902905759358_1285783491_n.jpg", 
"thumbnail": "https://scontent-gru2-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfp1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/1169888_444355602430404_585844977_n.jpg", 
"standart" : "https://scontent-gru2-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/12424518_166030477094416_1436870704_n.jpg" 
 }
```

Estou utilizando o sistema operacional Windows 7 versão 64 bits.

Eu estou tentando extrair dados do arquivo json acima e obter uma string na linguagem C#. Porém quando executo esse código na Unity não aparece nada no console.

```
using SimpleJSON;
using System;

public class ReadJson : MonoBehaviour {
    static void Main(string[]args){

        StreamReader input = new StreamReader("Assets/Resources/test.json");
        System.Console.WriteLine(input.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

Alguém teria uma ideia de uma maneira mais fácil para fazer isso ? Obrigada.

Answer (score 1):

Você não está conseguindo provavelmente porque importou o SimpleJSON mas não o StreamReader, que é o que utiliza de fato.

Pra você fazer o que deseja, vai ser preciso deserializar o arquivo `.json` veja como pode ficar seu código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class RootObject
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string low_resolution { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string standart { get; set; }
}

public class ReadJson : MonoBehaviour
{
    static public void Main()
    {
       using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/test.json")))
       {
           string json = r.ReadToEnd();
           List<RootObject> ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
       }

       Console.WriteLine(ro[0].url_short);
    }  
}
```

Também há respostas parecidas com sua dúvida nesse link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538428/loading-a-json-file-into-c-sharp-program